# In package.json scripts key: npm run or not?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, package.json

In an online tutorial, the package.json said (simplified):

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "npm run webpack -- --mode development"
},
```

I usually write, and it works:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development"
},
```

Is the first version in any way preferable? I understand the meaning of `--`, but I do not know whether encapsulating the command in another `npm run` call provides any benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call allows you to change the `webpack` command used, or add additional arguments, or even run an entirely different command at all.

For example, `npm run tsc` on my repos runs `npm run delDist && tsc`.

Comment: Thank you, still I don't get the difference. Isn't `npm run` redundant?

Comment: It's like making a function. You could set `dist` to `npm run devbuild && npm run test && npm run clean && npm run lint && npm run checkformat && npm run distBuild && npm run distTar`.

Comment: So there's no difference between the two approaches, only that `npm run` allows to execute other scripts commands?

Comment: Yes. You usually use sub-scripts like that for "utility" scripts which are reused often.